# Write LI with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am customizing an existing jQuery slideshow and wondered if anyone can help with changing the basic system which writes a Flickr source image into a background image CSS class of an LI to instead write it as an inline image within an LI.

The current code is:

```
$.each(r.query.results.photo,function(){
    data = this;
    // Creating a new LI element with the photo as its
    // centered background image:
    $('<li>', {
        css : {
            backgroundImage: 'url('+templateReplace(flickrSRC,data)+')',
            width: options.width
        }
    }).appendTo(ul);
});
```

So instead of writing the image into the background-image CSS class, is it possible to write the image src into an  item which is included inside the LI - so it becomes:

```
<li><img src="url('+templateReplace(flickrSRC,data)+')'" /></li>
```

I am struggling to work out how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$.each(r.query.results.photo,function(){
    data = this;
    // Creating a new LI element with the photo as its
    // centered background image:
    $('<li>').html($("<img>").attr("src", templateReplace(flickrSRC, data))).appendTo(ul);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to change this slider, you can use plugin linked below.This slider slides every html elements.
here is link to download : [http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/)

;)

Comment: Thanks nivoslider is great. But I am happy using the one I have already // thanks